# How do I solve this differential equation? $y'' - 2y' +4y = e^x\sin (x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have calculated the wronskian and while finding particular solution using variation of parameters. The integral becomes $$\int \sin(\sqrt{3}x)\sin(x)dx$$ I am stuck here. Have I done anything incorrectly prior to this? Please explain. The general solution to corresponding homogenous equation is $e^x(c_1\cos(\sqrt3x) + c_2\sin(\sqrt3x))$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You can rewrite the product as $\cos(\cdots) - \cos(\cdots)$. (However, in this case it's probably much easier to use the method of undetermined coefficients instead of variation of parameters.)

Comment: From Hans's hint,$$\int \!\sin \left( \sqrt {3}x \right) \sin \left( x \right) \,{\rm d}x
={\frac {\sin \left(  \left( \sqrt {3}-1 \right) x \right) }{2\,\sqrt 
{3}-2}}-{\frac {\sin \left(  \left( 1+\sqrt {3} \right) x \right) }{2+
2\,\sqrt {3}}}=-{\frac {\sqrt {3}\cos \left( \sqrt {3}x \right) \sin \left( x
 \right) }{2}}+{\frac {\sin \left( \sqrt {3}x \right) \cos \left( x
 \right) }{2}}
$$

Comment: There are of course more efficient ways as mentioned in the answers below, but there's nothing wrong with guessing $y = Ae^x (B \sin x + C \cos x)$ and obtaining the answer that way.

Comment: assignment said to solve this using variation of parameters. So I was stuck in sin(3–√x)sin(x)dx part

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Taking two ODEs

$$
\cases{y''-2y'+4y = e^x\sin x\\ z''-2z'+4z = e^x\cos x}
$$

we have

$$
z''+i y'' -2(z'+i y')+4(z+iy) = e^{x(i+1)}
$$

or

$$
u''-2u'+4u = e^{x(i+1)}
$$

To find the particular solution to this ODE is easier than the original problem. Assuming that the particular now is

$$
u_p = (a + i b)e^{x(c + id)}
$$

after substitution we can easily find that $u_p = \frac 12 e^{x(i+1)}$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

$$y'' - 2y' +4y = e^x\sin x$$
$$(ye^{-x})'' +3ye^{-x} = \sin x$$
Substitute $z=ye^{-x}$:
$$z''+3z=\sin x$$
Use variation of constant method with the guess:
$$z_p=A \sin x$$
$$\implies A =\dfrac 12 \implies z_p=\dfrac 12 \sin x$$
$$\boxed {y_p=\dfrac 12 e^x \sin x}$$

Answer (score 2):

Noting that the derivative of $e^x$ is itself, I would guess $Ae^x (B \sin(x) + C \cos(x))$ for the particular solution:

$$y = Ae^x (B \sin x + C \cos x)$$
$$y' = Ae^x (B \cos x - C \sin x + B \sin x + C \cos x) = Ae^x ((B -  C) \sin x + (B + C) \cos x)$$
$$y'' = Ae^x ((B - C)\cos x - (B + C) \sin x + (B -  C) \sin x + (B + C) \cos x) = Ae^x (-2C \sin x + 2B \cos x)$$

Hence $Ae^x (-2C \sin x + 2B \cos x - 2(B -  C) \sin x - 2(B + C) \cos x + 4B \sin x + 4C \cos x)$ $= e^x \sin x$.

The left-hand side is equivalent to $Ae^x (2B \sin x + 2C \cos x)$, which forces $2AB = 1, 2AC = 0$. We must therefore have $C = 0$, which leaves $AB = \frac{1}{2}$.

Hence our particular solution is $y_p = \boxed{\frac{1}{2} e^x \sin x}$.